# Adding a range to Wordpress post pagination

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I have some very long posts, some have more than 50 pages(using nextpage shortcode) and when using wp_link_pages it give me 50 internal post links, clearly this isn't usable.

How can I add a range to the wp_link_pages function?

The output should look like this: ...45678...

**EDIT**:

For a point of reference see here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_link_pages

**EDIT 10/1/12**:

I've got the logic for this figured out but now I need to figure out how to add it to the existing wp_link_pages function:

```
function limitPagination(){
    $displayPages = 5;
    $firstPage = 1;
    $lastPage = $numpages > 5;

    while($numpages > $displayPages){
            if(($pageNow > $firstPage +2) && ($pageNow < $lastPage - 2)){
                    echo (($pageNow - 2).($pageNow - 1).$pageNow.($pageNow + 1).($pageNow + 2));
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See below URL i think it is very help full to you.

http://wp-ultra.com/2011/07/adding-pagination-to-the-twenty-eleven-theme-without-a-plugin/

http://www.kriesi.at/archives/how-to-build-a-wordpress-post-pagination-without-plugin

http://design.sparklette.net/teaches/how-to-add-wordpress-pagination-without-a-plugin/

**Update answer after your comment**

**A Better wp_link_pages() for WordPress**

**See URL**: http://bavotasan.com/2012/a-better-wp_link_pages-for-wordpress/

http://www.velvetblues.com/web-development-blog/wordpress-number-next-previous-links-wp_link_pages/

If you’ve written a long post, WordPress provides the  quicktag so you can divide it into multiple pages. All you need to do is make sure that the theme you are using has included the wp_link_pages() function somewhere in the single post/page template. The function works perfectly, except when it comes to wanting to style it using CSS. The default HTML output of the function looks like this:

```
<p>
   Pages: 1 <a href="http://yoursite.com/2008/layout-test/2/">2</a> <a href="http://yoursite.com/2008/layout-test/3/">3</a>
</p>
```

You can modify what appears before and after the page numbers, so you can easily include a class there, but the issue is with the current page number. The “1″ in the example above isn’t wrapped in an HTML tag so there is no way to style it. Here’s a customized version of the function that you can add to your functions.php to change all that:

**Read more see below URL**

http://bavotasan.com/2012/a-better-wp_link_pages-for-wordpress/

Comment: Thanks Abid, but these are all related to the main blog loop, not the single post pages. Just to give you a better point of reference see my link above.

Comment: So how would I modify that function to only show the current page plus 2 links before & 2 links after? I could probably do it with javascript but i'd rather have it output the correct way in the first place.